# How can i set a variable value into an input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Is it possible to set an input value based on an inserted variable in jquery?

i would like to set the input of an input field into another input field. 
example:

```
<input type="timepicker" name="duur" value="" placeholder="Duur" id="endduur"/>
                <input type="timepicker" name="mytime" value="" placeholder="endtime" id="endtimestatusduur"/>
```

i would like to get the value of the input id "endduur＂ and set the same value into the input field with the id "endtimestatusduur"
i think it needs to be something like this：

```
endduur = $("#endduur").val();
      function endtimestatus() {
    var arr = [];
    $.each(arguments, function() {
        $.each(this.split(':'), function(i) {
            arr[i] = arr[i] ? arr[i] + (+this) : +this;
        });
    })

    return arr.map(function(n) {
        return n < 10 ? '0'+n : n;
    }).join(':');
}
      endtimestatus = endtimestatus(starttimestatus, endduur),
      endtimestatusduur = $("#endtimestatusduur").val(endtimestatus);
```

Comment: #endtimestatusduur doesn't exist in your HTML, do you mean #endtimestatus?

Comment: Srry i meant #entimestatusduur i've edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Use change method. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#endduur').datepicker({
weekStart: 1,
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        change: function(time){
         $("#endtimestatusduur").val($(this).val());
    }
});
});
```

For more details: http://timepicker.co/options/

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/6dtML/3/)**

Comment: That doesnt set an value into the entimestatusduur:(

Comment: @Rene: Updated answer. Please check.

Comment: @Rene: Is it helpful?

Comment: It is helpful but i have a timepicker on the first input field but then it wont set the value into the other input field. Only when i type in the first input field. How can i make this possible

Comment: I doesnt seem to work:( i am using a timepicker not a datepicker dont know if that is relevant

Comment: can you make [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code html and relevant jquery?

Comment: @Rene: Which timepicker library you are using?

Comment: @Rene: Check the latest one bro :)

Comment: it doesnt work still dont know why it wont. because i just paste the code from yours to mine..

Comment: i dont get any even when i log it puts the right variables out